# Image not saved as jpeg in firebase storage

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, base64, cordova-plugins, firebase-storage

I am currently working on an ionic project which uses the camera from cordova. I am able to take the image, store in ionic storage and also upload to firebase storage. However, the image is not saved as `jpeg` and instead in `application/octet-stream`.

```
  takePicture() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      console.log(imageData)
      // Add new photo to gallery
      this.photos.unshift({
        data: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData
      });

      // Save all photos for later viewing
      this.storage.set('photos', this.photos);
      //save to firebase storage
      const storageRef = firebase
        .storage()
        .ref('photos/img.jpeg')
      storageRef.putString(imageData, 'base64'), {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg'
      }


    }, (err) => {
      // Handle error
      console.log("Camera issue: " + err);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the API documentation, [putString()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#putstring) takes three arguments:

> Parameters
>
> - data: string
>
> The string to upload.
>
> - Optional format: StringFormat
>
> The format of the string to upload.
>
> - Optional metadata: UploadMetadata
>
> Metadata for the newly uploaded object.

The third argument is where you specify the content type.  Right now, you are passing two arguments, and the content type isn't part of that. It looks like you have the closing parenthesis in the wrong place:

```
storageRef.putString(imageData, 'base64', {
    contentType: 'image/jpeg'
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Doug, the error was due to the closing parenthesis as you have mentioned. Since two of the three arguments were optional, I was able to get away with my two parameters.